# Composing *many* completable futures

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

All the available literature shows `CompletableFuture` composition where a single future is composed with another using `thenCompose` to return a `CompletableFuture<ResultType>`.

In my circumstance I have a single initial `seedFuture` which yields *many* pieces of data instead of one, each of which requires further async work.

```
    final CompletableFuture<List<NeedsMoreAsyncWork>> seedFuture = supplyAsync(() -> {
        // do async work
    }, someExecutor);
```

Can this be expressed using a fluent API, so the end result is a `List<ComposableFuture<ResultType>>`? Or must I revert to using a `for` loop?

Comment: if you can compute the futures in parallel, you can use join and allOf... and sometimes a for loop is the best solution!

Comment: Your example code is not helpful to illustrate your issue. Basically, *every* example of `supplyAsync` boils down to passing a supplier that will “do async work”. You have not added anything *specific to your problem*.

Answer (score 1):

The completable future API only has a method to run the futures in parallel: `CompletableFuture.allOf(...)`.

If you need to run the futures in the order they appear in the list, then the only option I'm aware of is a custom loop:

```
List<Object> objects = ...
CompletableFuture loop = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
for (Object object : objects) {
   loop = loop.thenCompose( r -> future(object));  
}
```

The main issue with this solution is that if you have **many** futures, it could cause a StackOverflow exception. You can prevent it using the [Trampoline pattern](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/trampoline/). An implementation of this pattern is available via `com.ibm.sync:asyncutil`. [The project is on GitHub](https://github.com/IBM/java-async-util).